# Android: Class problem

Tags: java, android, class

I've created a class called website, and want to access it like a variable so I can update values to it, probably better explained below:

```
Website w = new Website();
w.URL="stackoverflow.com";
```

Here's the code for the class:

```
class Website {
         public String URL;
         public Website(){
             URL = "";
         }

}
```

I would also like to add a method such as this:

```
public long save() {
     return db.save(URL);
}
```

This (the method) isn't working for me at the moment

Comment: I changed the class name from Credential to Website.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still remains...

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: A null pointer exception

Comment: Other classes I've seen seem to use static, but this makes me unable to change the URL.

Comment: please post more code around this two lines: `Website w = new Website(); w.URL="stackoverflow.com";` and also stack trace of the exception.

Comment: What if I have a void, e.g.:

public void saveWebsite() {
   db.save(URL);
}

Comment: Not understanding what exactly are you trying? The code you posted above is a method. Your class doesn't have a method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear, I will update the question, hang on a min. Btw, you are being very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it more OO way, hiding this URL variable from outside and letting change it's value from getter and setter methods. You can try this, maybe this will help.

In Website class

```
public class Website {
   private String URL;

   public Website(){
      this.URL = "";
   }

   public void setUrl(String url) {
      this.URL = url;
   }

   public String getUrl() {
      return this.URL;
   }

  public long save() {
     return db.save(this.URL);
  }

}
```

And then call it

```
Website w = new Website();
w.setUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
long someLongValue = w.save();
```

Comment: This was the answer I used in the end, but thankyou to all who tried to answer!